# C++, char* string modification

Tags: c++

I am new to C++.
I have a program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   char* str = "Test";
   *str = 'S';
}
```

The question is, why *str = 'S' crashes the program?
As far as I know str must be pointing to the first character of the string (well, char array), so in theory I should be able to modify it.
Is it because the memory is read-only for defined constant values?
I am using gcc 5.3.0.

Comment: "Is it because the memory is read-only for defined constant values?" Nailed it.

Comment: I think you can replace char* to char[] and then you can modify it.

Comment: This is invalid as of C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why *str = 'S' crashes the program?

Because you're not allowed to modify string literals. The C++ standard allows them to be stored in read-only memory.

In fact, if you enable compiler warnings, you get:

```
prog.cc:5:16: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
    char* str = "Test";
                ^~~~~~
```

Always use `const char*` when pointing to string literals: